# How to share data between sibling components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am still learning and I got stuck so I need to ask a question. My understanding of Input Output decorators is that I need to add selector to html of parent to be able to use them, but for my case I don't think it's the way to go, but someone can prove me wrong.

CASE: For readability purposes I have split components. I have one component, data-fetch-transform that gets the data form local JSON file and does some adjustments to it, and another one, that wants to take that data for further use.

PROBLEM: I am unsure how to read the data from one component in the other. On the example below, how can I get countryNumber and centerNumber result in my other component. I intend to have data-fetch-transform.component.ts just manipulate the data and used in other components

Target component

> project/src/app/data-use/data-use.component.ts

Data Source component

> project/src/app/data-fetch-transform/data-fetch-transform.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import * as data from '../../../../../data/Data.json';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-datafetch-transform',
      templateUrl: './datafetch-transform.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./datafetch-transform.component.css'],
    })
    export class DatafetchComponent implements OnInit {
      public dataList: any = (data as any).default;
      dataPointCount = this.data.length!!;
    
     uniqueValues = (dt: [], sv: string) => {
        var valueList: [] = [];
        for (let p = 0; p < this.dataPointCount; p++) {
          valueList.push(dt[p][sv]);
        }
    
        var uniqueValues = new Set(valueList);
        return uniqueValues.size;
      };
    
    countryNumber=this.uniqueValues(this.dataList, 'Country')
    centerNumber=this.uniqueValues(this.dataList, 'Center Name')
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

Comment: This is usually done with a service. Read more here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need another component for data manipulation (data-fetch-transform), you need a service (data-fetch-transform-service) where you should do the logic.

HERE IS WHAT YOU SHOULD HAVE IN THE SERVICE

```
 private _dataList = new behaviorSubject([]);
 public dataList$ = _dataList.asObservable();
    
        for (let p = 0; p < this.dataPointCount; p++) {
          // ... do your thing 
          _valueList.next(result);
        }
```

and in the component you just subscribe to the service:
declarations:

```
private _subscription = new Subscription()
```

in constructor:

```
private dataService:DataFetchTransformService
```

and in ngOnInit:

```
this_subscription.add(this.dataService.dataList$.subscribe((response:any)=>{
this.data = response;
}))
```

in ngOnDestroy():

```
ngOnDestroy(){
this._subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I strongly suggest to stop using any since it can bring a lot of bugs up.
Also, as a good pattern, I always suggest use behaviorSubject only in the service as a private variable and user a public observable for data.

**WHY IS BETTER TO USE A SERVICE**
You can subscribe from 100 components and writing only 4 lines of code you bring the data anywhere.
**DON'T FORGET TO UNSUBSRIBE IN ngOnDestroy**
If you don't unsubscribe, you'll get unexpected behavior.

Comment: Also, I recommend you read this article:https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0